# I like to suggest proposal closures to be much harder

Tags: feature-request, area-51

Is it a good idea that a single person can close a proposal?

It would be nicer if proposal owner become aware of the closure and could discuss with it before the proposal getting closed actually, So false closures would be prevented.

Just like the questions a [On Hold] would be great, actually it is a bit surprising since a single question has a two step mechanism but a community proposal do not have an On Hold or something like that.

Comment: Immediately below the announcements box, at the right, there is a "create new discussion" link. Just click it, make your case, and the discussion automatically gets linked right below that announcement so everyone can see it. -- I've fixed your existing question so it now shows up on the proposal.

Comment: I am sure that Robert thought about it before closing your proposal. And he's not just "moderator", he's SE employee in charge of the whole Area 51 project.

Comment: I am sure about it too, but I like to suggest him to learn more about GENS while attempting to close its proposal.

Comment: Thanks animuson, I didnt find the button you are talking about, maybe it needs to be re designed, because I was desperatly searching for something up there, and still closing is very easy and it makes it unfair.

Comment: Life is unfair, but just to clarify - `customers and business partners and it's going to be expensive for me, that just hours after invitation someone closed the proposal!` - was the proposal for your business or to be a repository of knowledge (like other SE sites)? or both?

Comment: of course it was a knowledge based site and to be clear, Smallworld is a General Electric product, however  I didn't like to invite my customers and partners to a dead end! It is a bad thing for sure.

Comment: I was just asking to clarify, nothing more.

Comment: What are the downvotes for? do you guys know why you have downvoted this question? or there is a badge for certain number of downvotes that I do not know about, please share!

Comment: Since the question consisted two parts,and it was two questions in fact, I have deleted the first part and will post it later,So please update yours

Comment: @Iman Voting is different on Meta. Downvotes often reflect disagreement with a proposal, not just "this question is poorly written/no research/it's spam." As for "on hold," that's probably just an artifact of Area 51 having split off from the main codebase years ago, but "on hold" is purely cosmetic -- all it changes is the *label* applied. The only difference between an on-hold question and a closed question is whether a few days have elapsed since it was closed.

Comment: Thanks cpast, thats a relief, but if it is so, I like to propose a new voting system instead of downvoting which reduces someone's reputation.

Comment: If you guys disagree or agree with this suggestion, downvote is not a good way to express your disagreement, answer to the question and support your idea and disagreement  with proof and examples instead of ruining my reputation, I just dont know why. i am being down voted could one of you fifteen guys consider to write a comment? or should I say yes life is unfair in closing a proposal and when you ask why it is easily get closed, you are getting down voted cause life is still unfair.

Comment: @Iman Voting on meta is different, it's a sign of support or disagreement with your question. It seems that most people disagree with your request to soften the closure requirements on Area 51.

Comment: Well this kind of disagreement is reducing my reputation and could eventually ban me to upvote or answer to protected questions while is getting to lower than ten! so I will no more dare to propose any idea cause ofcourse a lot of people will diagree and I have understood that downvoting has much more fan than upvoting

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> why I as a proposal owner cannot discuss the closure?

The discussion section is still available even if a proposal is closed. You can start a discussion thread where the community can discuss and weigh in on the decision. But wrapping a second discussion section around the closure notices themselves doesn't make a lot of sense. Any discussion you create will will link directly into the proposal.

Comment: Well I didn't find the button, you may say I am blind, but blind or eagle, I am reporting this as a user.

Comment: And for a closure, just one vote is enough? against to eight people in this case?

Comment: Robert please update your answer

Comment: @Iman The fact that Robert is shown as having closed the proposal does *not* mean he didn't discuss this with the whole of SE to come to that conclusion. He is acting as an official representative of SE and its decisions there. So ultimately your reservations seem to not boil down to having a single person close the proposal but having SE close it without first asking the creators/followers/commiters of the proposal. But that's just the way it is, deal with it. As Robert explained, you have the means to discuss the closure within the community and with SE.

Comment: Thanks Christian, Thats much better, however I still think on holding a proposal before closure, is much better. giving it a chance to explain woudn't destruct or damage anything. it is a world wide rule in almost everything, Courts, Judges, Referees, every kind of decisions in almost any level is not taken without alerting.